# Create models dynamically in django from `views.py`

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to dynamically create a model in Django.
For example, I will get field names(say `FirstName` or `LastName`) from user input in `views.py`.
Now I want to know how to make a model on fly with the fields taken as input.

Comment: Did you tried googling the same ? What you found ? Did you go through this https://dynamic-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ ?

Comment: You can also investigate on HStore, JSONField, EAV